# Evaluate argument passed to a function in R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to evaluate the arguments passed to a function in R and store these in a object. Whatever I try R keeps giving me the variable name if I assign the argument using a variable instead of the value of the variable.

```
ar <- list()


f2 <- function(name, ..., env = parent.frame()) {
  arguments <- match.call()[-1]
  arguments <- arguments[setdiff(names(arguments), c("name", "env"))]
  env$ar[name] <- arguments
}

calibration <- 0.8

f2("sample", calibration = calibration) 

ar
```

Gives

```
$sample
calibration
```

Instead of

```
$sample
0.8
```

I am not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one-liner.  Note that `ar` need not be defined prior to running `f3` and if it were defined then it would be overwritten -- `append` or `modifyList` could be used instead for different behavior (not shown):

```
f3 <- function(name, ..., env = parent.frame()) {
         env$ar <- setNames(list(list(...)), name)
}

# test
calibration <- 0.8
solution <- "ohoh"
f3("sample", calibration = calibration, solution = solution)
```

giving:

```
> ar
$sample
$sample$calibration
[1] 0.8

$sample$solution
[1] "ohoh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution if people are interested in the future:

```
f2 <- function(name, ..., env = parent.frame()) {
  env$ar <- list()
  arguments <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
  arguments <- arguments[setdiff(names(arguments), c("name", "env"))]
  for (i in 1 : length(as.list(arguments))) {
    arguments[[i]] <- eval(arguments[[i]], envir = env)
  }

  env$ar[name] <- list(arguments)
}

calibration <- 0.8
solution <- "ohoh"
f2("sample", calibration = calibration)
ar 
f2("sample", calibration = calibration, solution = solution)
ar 
f2("sample", params = list(calibration = calibration, solution = solution))
ar
```